# How do I get the leftNavLibrary?

Tags: java, android, google-tv

I've visited :http://code.google.com/p/googletv-android-samples/source/browse/, the LeftNavBarLibrary is right there in front of me , how do I download this library? I don't see a download zip or link anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You follow the instructions on [the Source Checkout page](http://code.google.com/p/googletv-android-samples/source/checkout) to check out the git repository.

Comment: Thanks just noticed that page and I downloaded the github software.

Answer (score 1):

You have to clone the Git repository and inport the project into your IDE (Eclipse?).

Comment: After the project is imported into eclipse, do I set it as a library?

Comment: ADT should automatically set the library project flag. http://code.google.com/p/googletv-android-samples/source/browse/LeftNavBarLibrary/default.properties (android.library=true)